# UIScrollView - zoom all subviews inside (not only one)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Good Evening!

I am trying to zoom UIScrollView, more specific all sub-views placed inside.

As far I understand, I need to implement UIScrollViewDelegate method:

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return subView // <--- subview inside my scroll view
}
```

In my test projects zoom simply won't work until I do this. But, with this technique I can only zoom (1) single view. My scroll-view have dozens of sub-views which I want to be zoomed too. I can solve this by placing one UIView inside UIScrollView and then other sub-views inside this container view, but I will like to ask is there better solution?

I have used both automatic mechanism of pinch-to-zoom of scrollview and later played with my own pinch gesture recogniser:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
...
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pinchHandler:")

    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
.
.
.
func pinchHandler(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
{
    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
    {
        if recognizer.scale < 1.0 {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)                
        } else {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(2, animated: true)                
        }                       
    }
}
```

In both cases, only 1 view is zoomed (one passed as result of viewForZoomingInScrollView  function)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the way you're doing it (aka, make a content subview that contains all of your other subviews) is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Too bad :( Not sure if I am correct, can something be done by using transformations? Thanks Travis btw.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? I'm facing yout same issue now :S...

Comment: @LoryLory unfortunately not :(

Comment: Instead, I guess I have found a solution. You have to put inside the scrollview a single UIView, let's call it "container". Then, you have to add all your sub views to zoom to that container, all of them inside the container. Then, in method viewForZoomingInScrollView you simoly return the container. Try it, it works good for me :)

Comment: @LoryLory yep, I beleive this is the solution. Not sure why is not possible without container :(